# Java Exception message still has java.lang.Exception in the stack trace

Tags: java

In my Java app, I have a utility class that has global methods I can use in any situation.  The utility class has a method that throws an Exception to the parent class if something is misconfigured.  So for this example, I'm checking if an end date is after the start date before writing it to a Redis Cache:

```
public static boolean writeDates(Date date1, Date date2) throws Exception {

    boolean datesAreWrong = false;
    //Check dates are in correct format
    if(dateFormatIsWrong) {
      throw new Exception("Dates are not formatted correctly!");
    }
    //Check if dates are correct
    else if(datesAreWrong) {
       throw new Exception("Start date is set after the End Date!");
    }
    else {
       //write to Redis Cache
    }
}
```

And then whenever I call this method, it looks like:

```
public MyResponseObject writeDateToRedis(Date date1, Date date2) {

    MyResponseObject myResponseObject = new MyResponseObject();
    try {
      //config code
      myUtilClass.writeDates(date1, date2);
      //...
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      myResponseObject.setResponseCode(myConstants.failure_code);
      myResponseObject.setDescription("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
 }
```

The code works just fine, it's just since we started printing the error message to the UI it will display as "Error: java.lang.Exception:Start date is set after the End Date!".  For better readability and...prettiness? I want to hide the java.lang.Exception from the user error message.

Comment: Then don't print it

Comment: `getMessage()` should return "Start date is set after the End Date!", so to me there is no problem. Unless.... some other exception happend while checking the dates, you should verify that or post more code.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels In my production code, there can be multiple checks and errors, I just gave a small sample.  The Utility class method does many thing, so I want to show the user what went wrong.

Comment: That can't be, you're doing something apart from the code shown here then. `e.getMessage()` just returns the String `""Start date is set after the End Date!""` - so hwtaever you do in your UI, it does **not** only print the content of the `MyResponseObject` -

Comment: @AKSW I thought so too, but it is still coming out that way, so I thought I would try to ask SO.  I saw an answer a while ago that used .getCause().getMessage(), but that gave me a null pointer exception

Comment: `getCause` returns the wrapped exception. That's not the case here ...

Comment: there are several "string representations" of an "exception" .... : (in java), we have the `getMessage()` ...but also the `toString()` and `stackStrace()` can also be printed...it looks like "your UI" displays `toString()`, which you should override in your custom Exception class.

Comment: `getMessage` literally just returns the message, look at the constructor: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html#Exception-java.lang.String- if he really does print the content of the `MyResponseObject`, it can't happen. Still, I think he's not showing the wrong part of his code

Comment: Yeah I am suspicious this is what your code is actually doing. Like AKSW says, the error name should not be displaying from `getMessage()`. I just tested it myself to make sure. You *would* get that message if you just used the exception's `toString()` though.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own exception class and inherit from Exception. That will let you make everything up to your needs.